# Parse errors when using 'where' notation - how do I format this structure correctly?

Tags: haskell

This is the piece of the code that has the issue:

```
render world = RoomRender { title = "", desctext = x }  where x = 
         let boxThere = (blah blah blah)
         in (blah blah blah)
```

This is the error:

```
parse error on input `where'
   |
25 |     render world = RoomRender { title = "", desctext = x }  where x = 
   |                                                                                                        ^^^^^
```

Maybe there is some kind of tabbing issue? How to format this piece of code so it would work?

Comment: The first word after `where` sets the indentation column (that's the `x` in `x =` in your code). Anything less indented than that is parsed outside the `where`. I'd put the `x =` in the line below, so that `let ... in ...` can be on the right of the indentation column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a compiling example:

```
data Room = RoomRender {title :: String, desctext :: Int}
```

data Room = RoomRender {title :: String, desctext :: Int}

```
render world = RoomRender { title = "", desctext = x }
 where x = 
         let boxThere = undefined
         in undefined
```

another possibility is:

```
render world x = RoomRender { title = "", desctext = x }
                                               ---------^
```

very end, I think you miss an enter and then a withe space. Also could be those two.

I final advice: if you are looking for compilation error, please don't use the function `blah` because is type is `blah :: Blah -> Blah -> Blah`, so your code won't compile.

`undifined`, on the other hand, has type `undefined :: a`, so you can put that little momentous fix while you are finding you error